# jQuery view bound events in debugger IE

Tags: jquery, debugging, jquery-events

I have a problem with binding events and I need to see if an event is bound on any element.
For example when I have this code:

```
jQuery(selector).bind('load.background', function() { callback.call(this, bgPath);});
```

Where is it shown in debugger? I need to see it in IE developer tools, and there when I see my  variable in watches it look like on this image:

[image]

When I look in the Events tree (marked with small lightning) there is null as load value (even in case callback call succeed)

So where can I see if and what is bound on any element?

EDIT: Even in Chrome debugger is it null

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are not using jQuery selectors correctly. What is "load" refering to in your selector?

If it is the id of an element then the correct selector will be

```
jQuery(selector).bind('#load.background', function() { callback.call(this, bgPath);});
```

Comment: no load.background is namespaced event as far as I know..You can see whole my code in the second screenshot..is hard to see but the first breakpointed line is where I'm binding the event

Comment: Sorry I didnt get you correctly. Let me rephrase, what event you actually want to attach your event handler to?

Comment: ok sorry..I need to check and debug attaching events..its event fired onload of image..all is working excellent in major modern browsers but in IE<9 it doesn't..so I need to debug it:)